# Can a promise be used on any returning function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I usually see usage of npm library objects. They are typical functions with variable assignments. But usually on some functions I discover a promise could be used?

Does this mean a promise typically can be called on any returning function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope,

> Promise VS defer Object

defer Object is regular object with promise property to create defer object just call

```
var defer = Pormise.defer();
console.log(defer.promise);
```

any defer Object must has **resolve** and **reject** properties

**defer.promise** object has **status** property and **returned data property**

To convert any function to Promise Object you can wrap it with this

```
var promiseFunction = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   var result = anyFunction();
   if(result)
    resolve(result);
   else
    reject("Error")
});
```

To Use this

```
promiseFunction.then(function(result){

}).catch(function(error){

})
```

Comment: That's kind of unnecessary. If the function isn't async you can just do `Promise.resolve(myFunction())` and then start chaining.

Comment: where is the rejection scenario ?

Comment: @AhmedKesha - (whoops) anyway, please provide an ES6 reference to  `Promise.defer()` - spoiler alert - its been deprecated.

Comment: @AhmedKesha - reject it in the first `then` based on the returned value, if need be, using `Promise.reject` or by `throw`ing